# Typescript firebase photoUrl

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firebase

I have been using firebase in my react project, I am trying to display a the user's profile picture when they signup or sign in. When I tried doing that it shows an error

Here is code

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This only works if you are using the google or other OAuth providers like Github. I used the email and password so it didn't work you can either use the answer below or this can also work.

```
<img src={user?.photoURL! as string} alt="user_profile" />
```

Answer (score 3):

photoURL migth sometimes undefined(like no photoURL present). use default URL when photoURL is undefined.

```
<img src={user?.photoURL || 'www.default.imageurl'}>
```

Comment: I should mention that this is called fallback type check value: )